# How to run Multiple shell command without hangs in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Please someone help me!

Cannot run Multiple shell command in vb.net

when run the shell command in projects , the projects is hangs until command is finish.

And how to run without hangs in projects.

Thanks...
Sorry for Spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Process.Start() instead.  It is only slightly different but is more powerful. By default it will not wait. But you can wait by getting the process it creates and then waiting on it to exit.

Comment: Also research ProcessStartInfo

Comment: No. Instead of using shell, which then waits, use Process.Start, which does NOT wait. That means you can run 10-15 (etc) all at the same time.